# Resposive div element inside other div element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have two div element inside main div element I want those two div float left and the align center of the main div.
Something like this.

```
[ main div        [div1][div2]       ]
```

I have successfully floated the two divs but I am failing to assign the space on both the side. I mean to say align them in center.
 code to float left css

```
.container{
    width:100%
    height: auto;
} 

.img{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
.data{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}

html code
<div class="container">
    <div class="img"> image goes here</div>
    <div class="data">data goes here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `text-align:center;` on your `.img` css class?

Comment: yes. but it aligh text i want to align the div

Comment: something like this https://help.carbmanager.com/en/

Comment: @King11 yes i tried but no use

Answer (score 1):

if you write text-align:center to parent.It will align their children

thank you for comments

```css
.container{
    width:100%
    height: auto;
    text-align:center;
} 

.data{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/></div>
    <div class="data">data goes here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line / code only answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: @Paulie_D `We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context` Agreed on an answer needing explanation and context, but not on the long part. Sometimes short answers are enough. In some cases even better than long answers.

Comment: There is literally NO explanation here...let alone a "short" one.

Comment: I'm not even sure it satisfies the OPs requirement as the `data` div is below rather than to the right of the `img` div...

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the img and data div in a div, then float that div right with a 50% width. I prefer not to use floats; flexbox would be a better option in my opinion, but if you like floats, I put some code below you can try.

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="dataImgContainer">
        <div class="img"> image goes here</div>
        <div class="data">data goes here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Add below to the CSS sheet:

```
.dataImgContainer {
   width: 50%;
   float: right;
 }
```